# Customizing the format of JSON data from PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a webservice which gives data as json form mysql database.

**PHP webservice**

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('db', $conn);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id,group FROM faq");
    //$query content is:
    // Array ([id]=>faq1 [group]=>hardware) Array ([id]=>faq2 [group]=>software) 

    $faq = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $faq[] = $row // <= ????????
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    return json_encode($faq);
?>
```

**JSON output that I get**

```
[
    {
        "id": "faq1",
        "group": "hardware"
    },
    {
       "id": "faq2",
       "group": "software"
    }
]
```

**JSON output that I want to have**

```
[
    {
        "id": "faq1",
        "group": {
            "id": "hardware"
        }
   },
   {
       "id": "faq2",
       "group": {
            "id": "software"
       }
   }
]
```

I want to get this JSON data as result but I really couldn't have success on this. So how should I need to edit my "PHP webservice" to get this json result?

Comment: Not an answer but `mysql_` is deprecated, use `mysqli_` instead

Comment: What does your current code output?

Comment: @Henrique Barcelos I tried to summarize my code and for this I didn't mention my current json result. So, I'm not happy with my current result format:)

Comment: @Pete O'Connell I tried to summarize my code and for this I didn't mention my current json result. I've added it to my question now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$faq = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $faq[] = array(
      'id' => $row['id'],
      'group' => array(
         'id' => $row['group']
       )
   );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this first:

```
$row['group'] = Array('id' => $row['group']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct array like this

```
$arr = array();
$id = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $arr[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $arr[$i]['group']['id'] = $row['group'];
    $i++;
}

$json = json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: if you change `$id = 0;` as `$i = 0;` this works also. But @Michael Marr 's way looks like easier to me. Ofcourse thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$arrayJson["id"] = $row["id"];
$arrayJson["group"]["id"] = $row["group"];
echo json_encode($arrayJson)
```

Comment: Without using a `$i` counter as @chandresh_cool did, this gives only one object(the last one) after the while loop. Thanks anyway.

Comment: yeah , i forgot you have multiple rows :(